# groupby and max in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'c1': [4,7,9,0,3],
        'c2': [1,8,3,0,2]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to `groupby('id')` and take the maximum value among `c1` and `c2`.

The desired output:

```
data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'],
        'c': [4,8,9,0,3]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

First create `index` by `id`, get max per rows and then aggregate `max` if possible `id` are duplicated values:

```
df = data.set_index('id').max(axis=1).groupby(level=0).max().reset_index(name='c')
print (df)
  id  c
0  A  4
1  B  8
2  C  9
3  D  0
4  E  3
```

If `id` are not duplicated like in sample data remove aggregation:

```
df = data.set_index('id').max(axis=1).reset_index(name='c')
print (df)
  id  c
0  A  4
1  B  8
2  C  9
3  D  0
4  E  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`GroupBy.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
(data.melt(id_vars='id', value_name='c')
     .groupby('id', as_index=False)['c'].max()
)
```

output:

```
  id  c
0  A  4
1  B  8
2  C  9
3  D  0
4  E  3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do so and you don't necessarily need a groupby, but just a new column based on the values of "c1" and "c2".

I like to use np.where in those cases:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'c1': [4,7,9,0,3],
        'c2': [1,8,3,0,2]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data ["c"] = np.where (data["c1"] >= data["c2"], data ["c1"], data["c2"])
del data ["c1"]
del data ["c2"]
```

The first argument is the condition to evaluate, the second is the return value in case the condition is matched, the third is the "else".